# Does ssh-keyscan tell you if a server supports RSA or DSA keys?

Tags: ssh, key-generation

A question came up on the Unix & Linux SE site: [Checking if passwordless ssh authorization is possible without permission for sshd_config?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/75342/checking-if-passwordless-ssh-authorization-is-possible-without-permission-for-ss).

I immediately thought you could possibly infer this using the commands: `ssh-keyscan -t rsa <server>` and `ssh-keyscan -t dsa <server>`.

My logic is that if a server is returning either key, then it must support that type of key for users' use as well.

Is this assumption incorrect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are details... but, basically, early in the connection establishment, both client and server send to each other the list of algorithms (and thus key types) that they support. See [section 7.1 of RFC 4253](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4253#section-7.1).

Try `ssh -vvv the.ssh.server.name`. The debug messages will show you a lot of information of what the server returned, including the full lists of algorithms.

Comment: Yeah I figured the `ssh -vvv` would be another, probably more explicit, way but it's pretty verbose to be dumping on a noob. Hence my thinking of the `ssh-keyscan` approach. So is my thinking incorrect in the use of `ssh-keyscan` in that manner?

Comment: `ssh-keyscan` tells you which key types are used by the server for its own part. If a server has a key of a given type, then it has code to support that kind of key, but it does not necessarily mean that it will support similar key types for authenticating clients. And neither in the other direction. That's not a reliable inference to make.